# what does this error mean in general? and how I fix it in this case?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

The error message appears on Xcode that says "invalid operands to binary expression.

in my code I'm using an array of a struct, i'm trying to sort input data in an ascending order, and i'm getting this error message at the "if" condition shown in the print screen at this link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0mch2gbxcif0a20/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-27%20at%2012.45.45%20PM.png?dl=0

**The Code**

```
if (studentsInfo[i] > studentsInfo[i + 1]) {}
```

**The Error**

Invalid operands to binary expression ('students' and 'students')

Comment: Post the code and error here please. don't have a DROPBAAX account.

Comment: Have you defined a > operator for your student struct?

Comment: You need to add the declaration of `StudentsInfo` to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you compare in your program? As I see, you have to compare names, but all you do is compare an array element which is a struct data type.
If you are trying to compare names, you have to use dot "." operator to reach names. After yo compare names, you can change the elements's place.

Answer (score -2):

The error means that > only takes two arguments and you are using it for something else. In this case you are comparing an entire data structure that does not have an override for > operator and is an undefined behavior. StudentsInfo[i] is a data structure that has more than one element in it. Replace the StudentsInfo[i] with StudentsInfo[i].GPA or another element whose data type has a defined > operator.

Comment: I don't know where you got the undefined behaviour from.

Comment: Yep, the statement about undefined behavior is incorrect. Undefined behavior is something that compiles, but is not guaranteed to work. OP's code does not compile.